# SQL - Mathematical Operation as Output Column

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I, for example have two columns; person and action.  Each person, then, has to complete any action of their choosing up to 10 times. I would like to output a table showing each name and how many actions they each have left to complete.

To clarify, from the following table:

```
name       action  
a          kick
b          throw
a          run
c          duck
a          throw
```

I would like to produce the output:

```
name       numactionsleft
a          7
b          9
c          9
```

I have tried something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT name, 10-COUNT(*) as numactionsleft
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) -- unsure where to go from here or if this is the wrong
                -- train of thought entirely
```

But am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Why do you want `HAVING`?

Comment: Remove the `HAVING` and it should give you the result you want?

Comment: pls. tag DBMS (ms sql, oracle) which u r using

Comment: What's the expected result if 11 d rows are inserted into the table?

Comment: It was the start of thinking about how to do the mathematical operation other than in the `SELECT` statement - I by no means necessarily back this as the start of the correct method (as shown in my comment) - sorry if this caused confusion!